# Ubuntu 18.04 fails to start when more than 6 GPUs plugged in

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I am building a Linux machine with 8x GTX 1060 and it forever stays at

```
start user manager for uid 1
```

The PC can boot safely when there's only 6 GPUs onboard. If I switch back to Windows 10, it can boot and all GPUs can be utilised 100%.

I checked if it is the insufficient BIOS memory that prevents more than 6GPUs but it does not explain why Windows can boot.

Here's my PC specs.

```
TB250-BTC V6.0
HyperX Fury DDR4 16GBx2
1000W Power Supply
```

The NVIDIA driver I am using is nvidia 396.

Comment: Unfortunately due to time constraint my company has resorted to a 6 PCIE lanes motherboard. Will revisit this issue when I get to tinkering with the motherboard again.